# No 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed

Tags: ios, iphone, automatic-ref-counting

That line gives me a warning in the source code

```
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t queue;
```

No 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed

My project is non-ARC and I cannot change it at the moment.

How do I fix the warning? (nonatomic, assing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system needs any of those 3 attributes, if none is present, it will assume it's `assign` the chosen one. If you write `(nonatomic, assign)` it will work exactly the same way it's working now so, if it's working o, go ahead and write `assign`.